# Remove \n characters only from first line of xls while converting to csv Python pandas

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, dataframe

The first line of the excel contains words with \n character in each cell.
eg:

```
Month   "East North Central\n(NSA)" "East North Central\n(SA)"  "East South Central\n(NSA)"
```

So while converting to csv using this code :

```
data_xls = pd.read_excel('/home/scripts/usless/HP_PO_hist.xls', 'sheet1', index_col=4,skiprows=3)
data_xls.to_csv('HH_PO_output.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

It converts the chars after \n into new lines like :

```
,Month,"East North Central
(NSA)","East North Central
(SA)","East South Central
(NSA)","East South Central
```

But the expected output is like :

```
Month  East North Central (NSA)    East North Central (SA) East South Central (NSA)    East South Central (SA)
```

How to remove this \n character only from this index line while converting to csv in Python df?

Comment: Actually I tried to reproduce your sample but got no issues...may you share your original .xls file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the following dummy data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

columns=["Month", "East North Central\n(NSA)", "East North Central\n(SA)", "East South Central\n(NSA)"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

When exporting to csv via `df.to_csv` I get the same line break behavior (pandas 0.19.2):

```
,Month,"East North Central
(NSA)","East North Central
(SA)","East South Central
(NSA)"
```

One solution for this is to simply replace the `\n` with whitespaces like this:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("\n", " ")
```

This provides the desired result:

```
,Month,East North Central (NSA),East North Central (SA),East SouthCentral (NSA)
```